# Problem in tracking my position with Gocoder python

Tags: python, geolocation

I'm student and i'm working in project where i want to track my exact position with python.
I have problem everytime when i try to track my position, it doesn't give an exact position
it gives the wrong position with different city
i'm using Geocoder library

`import geocoder g = geocoder.ip('me') a=g.latlng b=g.city`

my current country is Tunisia
[This is my current position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZWrw.png)

[This is what Geocoder return to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us1gD.png)

Is there a solution for this?? Is the problem with my provider?